# Set view of figure in MATLAB from the command line

Tags: matlab, visualization

How do you rotate a figure to X-Y, X-Z or Y-Z in MATLAB from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function [`view`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/view.html)

```
view([0 90]) % X-Y
view([0 0]); % X-Z
view([90 0]) % Y-Z
```

Answer (score 1):

The position of the viewer (the viewpoint) determines the orientation of the axes. You specify the viewpoint in terms of azimuth and elevation, or by a point in three-dimensional space.

```
view(2) sets the default two-dimensional view, az = 0, el = 90.
view(3) sets the default three-dimensional view, az = –37.5, el = 30.
```

For eg if you want to see the x-z plane

Set the view along the y-axis, with the x-axis extending horizontally and the z-axis     extending vertically in the figure.

```
view([0 0]);
```

Similarly for x-y: view([0 90) and y-z: view([90 0])

For detailed Info:
http://www.mathworks.in/help/techdoc/ref/view.html